# creating tuple from int in c++

Tags: c++, tuples

Recently i switched from python to C++ due to university requirement and I'm having a hard time understanding the synthax for C++.

I have problem with my assignment where i have to take in a number of integers and return them a tuples. This requires me to store the integers as tuple at different points

The code is as follows:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tuple>
    #include <functional>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      int times;
      cin >> times;
      //scanf("%d", &times);

      int x_point;
      int y_point;
      int k;
      int iA[times];
      for ( k = 1; k <= times; k++)  
          cin >>  x_point >> y_point;
          iA[k] = make_tuple(x_point, y_point);

    }
```

I get the error  "error: cannot convert 'std::tuple' to 'int' in assignment" I understand where the error occurs, but i do not know which data type to define iA as.

```
     tuple iA[times]
```

Does not work. Is there anyway I could do this?  Thank you

Comment: You may refer to the documentation regarding [`make_tuple(x_point, y_point);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple). Also use braces to enclose the `for()` loops body `{}`, indentation isn't enough to group the statements unlike in python.

Comment: "But I do not know which data type to define `iA` as" As a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) of course, what else? Please read the docs. The return type of `std::make_tuple` is the type you want `iA` to be.

Comment: As a `std::tuple<int, int>` one would think...

Comment: The condition in the loop is wrong. Start with 0 and use < instead of <=

Answer (score 2):

the `make_tuple` returns a temporary object of `tuple` to an `object of tuple` not to `int[ index ]`. That why complier tell you:

error: cannot convert 'std::tuple' to 'int' in assignment

you need something like this( for example )
`std::tuple< int, int, float > my_tuple = std::make_tuple< 1, 1, 1.1 >();`

---

In c++ first the `std::pair` is created and the `std::tuple` is a complex and advanced use if `std::pair`.
In fact std::pair is easy to use and understand but `std::tuple` not because it has more **template programming** than `std::pair`.
As I can see you are confusing `std::tuple` in **python** with likewise in **c++**.
In **c++** you have declare the type **explicitly**, except after **c++11** that you can use **auto**:

`auto my_tuple = std::make_tuple< 1, "hello" >();`

Also with `std::pair` , print the outputs in easy:
`std::cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << std::endl;`

but with `std::tuple` you should use:
`std::cout << std::get< 0 >( my_tuple ) << std::endl;` for the first index.
So some beginner that has no experience with **template** would have the hard time to managed it.

---

**I am beginner like you**, so  I suggest you first use `std::pair` then go ahead and  use `std::tuple` because it is a little bit complex for beginner in c++.

---

Shortly see my githup that has a lot example [1000_examples_with_c++](https://github.com/k-five/1000_examples_with_cpp/tree/master/07_Utility_Library/11_Tuple)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip! Doing pair wont work as tuple are the requirement for my assignment.

Comment: Please wait so that I edit my answer in clear way :)

Comment: When i do my_tuple = std::make_tuple< 1, 1, 1.1 >(); it says that my_tuple is not defined. Tried using std:: tuple <int, int> t(x_point, y_point) too but i get  variable 'std::tuple<int, int> t' has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: Hey k-five! That was insightful, kind of understand it better now. However, for std::cout << std::get< 0 >( my_tuple ) << std::endl; . What if i want to return it as a tuple? Taking a user input eg 3 5 and return it as a tuple of (3,5) while storing this tuple at a location which can be accessed later on!

Comment: returns a `std::tuple` no possible, except after **c++17**, but `std::pair` is possible `return { 1, 1.1 };` as pair

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int times;
    cin >> times;

    int x_point;
    int y_point;
    int k;
    vector<tuple <int,int>> iA; 
    for ( k = 0; k <times; k++)  {
        cin >>  x_point >> y_point;
        iA.push_back(make_tuple(x_point, y_point));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work for me. This also requires library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This should work with the c++11 compiler options.

Comment: *"Tuple support is currently experimental"* - Only if you live in the past. Or what else do you mean with "currently"?

Comment: Tuple support isn't experimental. Just write that C++11. Be specific about compiler flags.

Answer (score 2):

`int iA[times];` is not standard C++ if `times` is not a compile-time constant. It's a GCC extension (called variable-length arrays, or VLAs) which may or may not make it into future versions of C++. You must not use if you want your code to be portable.

The correct, easy and normal way is to use **`std::vector`**. The element type should be `std::tuple<int, int>`, because you want to store pairs of integers. And the variable name `iA` is meaningless, so why not just call it `integers`? Or maybe you can come up with an even more descriptive name.

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> integers;
```

There is no need to initialise the vector to hold `times` elements initially. You can use its `push_back` member function to add elements dynamically:

```
integers.push_back(std::make_tuple(x_point, y_point));
```

---

Your current code also fails because it treats arrays as if they were one-based. But they are zero-based (i.e. their indices go from *0* to *n-1*).

And you are missing the `{` / `}` curly braces around the block of your `for` loop, which means that only the `cin >>  x_point >> y_point;` line is looped.

What else? Don't use `using namespace std`, don't declare local variables before you use them, make your variable names more descriptive, and don't use the facilities in `<stdio.h>` (like `scanf`).